# what is the difference between $\aleph_0$ and $ \beth_0$

Tags: set-theory, cardinals, transfinite-recursion

I have been looking at the difference between $\aleph_0 $ and $\beth_0$ and I cant conclude the difference.

Any help will be much appreciated

Thanks in advance

Comment: I've removed the large cardinals tag, since it has nothing to do with the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[There is no difference.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beth_number#Definition) The $\aleph$- and $\beth$-**hierarchies** are of course quite different, and so we should expect the symbol "$\beth_0$" to only show up when we're talking about iterated powersets, so in that sense the difference in symbols provides a context clue; but the actual specific cardinals are the same.

Comment: Thank you, so $\aleph_0$ and $\beth_0 $ are the same but in the context of their hierarchies you said we consider $\beth$ when we talk about iterated power sets, what do you mean by this?  Online it says $\beth$ does not necessarily index all of the numbers indexed by $\aleph$.

Comment: @Maths The $\beth$-hierarchy is defined by: $\beth_0=\aleph_0$, $\beth_{\alpha+1}=2^{\beth_\alpha}$, and $\beth_{\lambda}=\sup\{\beth_\alpha: \alpha<\lambda\}$ for $\lambda$ limit. Every $\beth_\alpha$ is an $\aleph$-number - that is, for each $\alpha$ there is some $\beta$ such that $\beth_\alpha=\aleph_\beta$. However, **the converse need not hold**. For example, suppose the [continuum hypothesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuum_hypothesis) fails. Then $\aleph_1$ is between $\beth_0$ and $\beth_1$: $\aleph_1$ is not a $\beth$ number at all. (cont'd)

Comment: On the other side of the aisle, it's consistent that $\aleph_\alpha=\beth_\alpha$ **always**; this is the [generalized continuum hypothesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuum_hypothesis#The_generalized_continuum_hypothesis). The point is that *a priori* - that is, just from the [ZFC axioms alone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zermelo%E2%80%93Fraenkel_set_theory), with no additional set-theoretic assumptions - all we know about the $\beth$ hierarchy is that it describes *some* of the infinite cardinals. (At this point you should review the definition of the $\aleph$ numbers for contrast.)